# How to generate a WADL in IBM Integration Designer (IID) 8.5.6 from a REST project?

Tags: java, rest, wadl

I'm not find a way to generate or export the WADL from the REST project by the IBM Integration Designer 8.5.6 from a REST project which already create in the IDE and test with success with SoapUI 5.1.13.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add ?WSDL in the end of the endpoint and WADL should get generated

Comment: 00000122 RequestProces I org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor logException The following error occurred during the invocation of the handlers chain: WebApplicationException (405) with message 'null' while processing GET request sent to http://localhost:9080/ProjectRS/Mediation/RS?WSDL 00000122 ResourceRegis I org.apache.wink.server.internal.registry.ResourceRegistry filterDispatchMethods The system cannot find any method in the com.project.rs.RS class that supports GET. Verify that a method exists.

Comment: You may be missing description file which have this information, for example in apache axis its wsdd files which once we register to apache axis server, tells the server about the web service.

Comment: This may be helpful link,http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/bpm/library/techarticles/1312_hyakuna/1312_hyakuna.html http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSQP76_8.6.0/com.ibm.odm.dserver.rules.res.console/topics/tsk_rescons_tds_downld_wsdl_wadl.html and its not compulsory to have a WADL for all the REST services